# Windows 8 - getting a reference to the main Page from a UserControl

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

In my sample Windows 8 app I have a Popup UserControl serving as a custom SettingsPane where I want to let to choose MainPage  background color.

The problem is I can’t access MainPage’s children from UserControl’s code behind file - I named the root grid and I still get the error `The name “mainGrid” doesn’t exist in the current context`. I know this issue has been solved for WPF but none of these solutions seems to work  for a Windows 8 app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply pass a reference to Main when you use the user control. Have this as a property on your user control that you set at runtime.

Another option is that if you need to do operation X when something happens in the user control you can simply define an event in your user control, and implement an event handler for that event in your MainPage.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on both of the approaches with some more detail? Code samples would be helpful. Especially, the second scenario seems to suit my needs.

Comment: Give this a whirl: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow.aspx  then cast that to a reference of (MainPage) however the children may be private and you'll have to provide an accessor to it if it is private. Try it first though.